# Howto add a link to a library in autoconf configure script / makefile

Tags: gcc, boost, autotools, autoconf

I am an autotools newb
and I have difficulties figuring out howto easily
link a specific library into one of the configured targets.

I have a source package that I want to build the usual way:
./configure && make && make install

Unfortunately one of the cpps has a missing reference to another library.
Compiling it by hand (adjusting the commandline) works. But I would rather
"patch" the compile script.
Where is the standard place to edit linking references?

```
 undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()
```

That is my error message btw.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to add the relevant `-l` flag to `AM_LDFLAGS` in `Makefile.am`; e.g.:

```
AM_LDFLAGS = -lboost_system-mt
```

Note that Boost libraries generally end in a suffix—a sequence of letters that indicates the build configuration.  In the above example, the suffix is `-mt`.  This could be different in your installation (though the `-mt` variant is commonly available on POSIXy systems, IME).

I do something like this:

```
AM_LDFLAGS = -lboost_system$(BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX)
```

`BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX` is a precious variable (see `AC_ARG_VAR`) that defaults to `-mt`.

Comment: @Braden automake builds a `LIBS` variable from within the configure script itself; following this for all cases can result in multiple links for the same library  in the make commands -- this can yield an error with different compilers

Answer (score 1):

Use `ax_cxx_check_lib.m4` because boost_system does not have any extern "C" symbols (unmangled names) that can be checked with `AC_CHECK_LIB`:

http://ac-archive.sourceforge.net/guidod/ax_cxx_check_lib.m4

Download the file above and name it `acinclude.m4`, and put it in the `m4` folder in your project root.

In `configure.ac`:

```
AC_LANG_PUSH([C++])

AX_CXX_CHECK_LIB([boost_system-mt],[boost::system::generic_category()],[BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX="-mt"],[BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX=""])

AC_LANG_POP([C++])

AC_SUBST(BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX)
```

In `Makefile.am`:

```
[artifact_name]_LDFLAGS = -lboost_system@BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX@
```