# undefined reference to boost::system::system_category() when compiling

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to compile a program on Ubuntu 11.10 that uses the Boost libraries. I have the 1.46-dev Boost libraries from the Ubuntu Repository installed, but I get an error when compiling the program.

`undefined reference to boost::system::system_category()`

What is it that I do wrong?

Comment: That's not a compiler error, it's a _linker_ error. You need to link to the Boost.System library.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

The boost library you are using depends on the boost_system library. (Not all of them do.)

Assuming you use gcc, try adding `-lboost_system` to your compiler command line in order to link against that library.

Comment: I am using a g++ Makefile for the compilation. Where does one usually put such flags?

Comment: How the compiler/linker command line is assembled varies greatly from case to case. Why don't you paste your Makefile (or the relevant parts of it) into your question? That way, you could get an answer that works in your specific case.

Comment: That Makefile is automatically generated by automake. So what you actually want to do is change your Makefile.am or configure.ac.

Comment: Ok, I edited Makefile.am and added `-lboost_system`, so it looked like this: `sslsniff_LDFLAGS = -lssl -lboost_filesystem -lpthread -lboost_thread -llog4cpp -lboost_system`. It didn't help though...

Comment: Still the same error? Did you run `autoreconf` afterwards? Also, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2270073/1269546) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2057472/1269546) might help you with your autotools configuration.

Comment: I replaced `sslsniff_LDFLAGS` with `sslsniff_LDADD` in Makefile.am and that did NOT work. Then I kept both `sslsniff_LDFLAGS` and added `sslsniff_LDADD = -lboost_system -lssl -lboost_filesystem -lpthread -lboost_thread -llog4cpp`. Then I was able to compile. Thank you for the help!

Comment: This advice doesn't help me on cygwin.

Comment: my target file had to first then the libraries

Comment: On some systems libboost_system needs to be installed separately. eg Raspbian `apt install libboost1.67-dev` only gets the header files; the .so files are in separate packages eg `apt install libboost-system1.67` (no need for the -dev suffix in that one as this is just for linking purposes)

Answer (score 77):

Linking with a library that defines the missing symbol (`-lboost_system`) is the obvious solution, but in the particular case of Boost.System, a misfeature in the original design makes it use `boost::system::generic_category()` and `boost::system::system_category()` needlessly. Compiling with the flag `-DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED` disables that code and lets a number of programs compile without requiring `-lboost_system` (that link is of course still needed if you explicitly use some of the library's features).

Starting from Boost 1.66 and [this commit](https://github.com/boostorg/system/commit/829a1320a7bef3ade74d6691fdcfe72e0b6917e9), this behavior is now the default, so hopefully fewer and fewer users should need this answer.

As noticed by @AndrewMarshall, an alternative is to define `BOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY` which enables a header-only version of the code. This was [discouraged](https://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2017/10/239106.php) by Boost as it can break some functionality. However, since 1.69, header-only seems to have [become the default](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/system/doc/html/system.html#changes_in_boost_1_69), supposedly making this question obsolete.

Comment: thanks!!! nothing helped since I use boost 1.41 (Centos SL) the only thing that freed me, is using the -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED

Comment: Actually what you may want is -DBOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY

Comment: @Andrew it depends, but indeed both should work here. Whether BOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY or BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED is preferable depends on each use case.

Comment: Interestingly the new Boost 1.66 behavior of havinging _less_ references to system_category() etc. may introduce _new_ link issues in the presence of link ordering issues. See https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/pull/2236 for example

Comment: @pixelbeat Arguably that's a bug in boost or in the cmake module for boost, it should handle dependencies automatically. But yes, any fix can uncover latent issues :-(

Comment: If you use CMake just add 'add_definitions(-DBOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY)'

Comment: The only fixed that worked for me with Boost 1.68 was to define `BOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY`.

Comment: @sakra If `-lboost_system` fails, you are using it wrong. This answer was specifically about programs that do not use Boost.System, but where a bug still required linking with the library. Most likely you are actually using Boost.System (or a library that uses it). If that is not the case, I encourage you to post a new question with a testcase (or possibly report the issue to boost).

Comment: Linking boost_system last fixed the issue for me. Using boost 1.68 with cmake on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - I'm having a similar problem on MacOS with boost 1.70.0..  Are you saying that the compiled boost dynamic libraries libboost_system and libboost_filesystem must be recompiled with BOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY or BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED, or that the code that includes boost headers needs to be compiled with one of those defined?

Comment: @SMGreenfield Your code should define these before including the boost headers, either in an include file or (my personal preference) as part of your build system (eg CMake `target_compile_definitions`).

Answer (score 28):

Another workaround for those who don't need the entire shebang: use the switch

`-DBOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY`.

If you use CMake, it's `add_definitions(-DBOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY)`.

Comment: I recently came across this problem. Nothing works except this one. I wonder if this is still discouraged by boost as mentioned in Marc Glisse's answer.

Comment: quote "Boost.System is now header-only. A stub library is still built for compatibility, but linking to it is no longer necessary."

Answer (score 17):

The above error is a linker error... the linker [a program that takes one or more objects generated by a compiler and combines them into a single executable program.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29)

You must add `-lboost_system` to you linker flags which indicates to the linker that it must look for symbols like `boost::system::system_category()` in the library `libboost_system.so`.

If you have main.cpp, either:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -lboost_system
```

OR

```
g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ main.o -lboost_system
```

Comment: the space between -l and the library name is incorrect. you should use -lboost_system

Comment: I found that centos didnt care about the position of -l but ubuntu did, has to be at the end.

Answer (score 8):

When using CMAKE and find_package, make sure it is :

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system ...)
```

and not

```
find_package(boost COMPONENTS system ...)
```

Some people may have lost hours for that ...

Answer (score 6):

I got the same Problem:

```
g++ -mconsole -Wl,--export-all-symbols -LC:/Programme/CPP-Entwicklung/MinGW-4.5.2/lib  -LD:/bfs_ENTW_deb/lib   -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -LC:/Programme/CPP-Entwicklung/boost_1_47_0/stage/lib   \
 D:/bfs_ENTW_deb/obj/test/main_filesystem.obj \
 -o D:/bfs_ENTW_deb/bin/filesystem.exe -lboost_system-mgw45-mt-1_47 -lboost_filesystem-mgw45-mt-1_47
```

> D:/bfs_ENTW_deb/obj/test/main_filesystem.obj:main_filesystem.cpp:(.text+0x54):
>   undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()

**Solution was to use the debug-version of the system-lib:**

```
g++ -mconsole -Wl,--export-all-symbols -LC:/Programme/CPP-Entwicklung/MinGW-4.5.2/lib  -LD:/bfs_ENTW_deb/lib   -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -LC:/Programme/CPP-Entwicklung/boost_1_47_0/stage/lib   \
 D:/bfs_ENTW_deb/obj/test/main_filesystem.obj \
 -o D:/bfs_ENTW_deb/bin/filesystem.exe -lboost_system-mgw45-mt-d-1_47 -lboost_filesystem-mgw45-mt-1_47
```

But why?

Comment: Can it be that somewhere was defined some debug flag, so you had other libs built in debug or g++ was producing debug obj ?

Answer (score 4):

When I had this, problem, the cause was the ordering of the libraries.  To fix it, I put `libboost_system` last:

```sh
g++ mingw/timer1.o -o mingw/timer1.exe  -L/usr/local/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib \
    -lboost_timer-mgw53-mt-1_61 \
    -lboost_chrono-mgw53-mt-1_61 \
    -lboost_system-mgw53-mt-1_61
```

This was on mingw with gcc 5.3 and boost 1.61.0 with a simple timer example.

Comment: This was my problem too. I included it via CMake and, for whatever reason, assumed dependencies and ordering were worked out in the FindBoost script. Really, though, my problem was always using shared libraries and never paying attention, then moving to static libraries and getting build errors. Oops.

Comment: This fixed it for me as well... previous to this solution the only thing that worked was defining BOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY. On Ubuntu 18.04, boost 1.68, with cmake. My fix: target_link_libraries(executable pthread ssl crypto boost_system)

Answer (score 2):

in my case, adding `-lboost_system` was not enough, it still could not find it in my custom build environment. I had to use the advice at [Get rid of "gcc - /usr/bin/ld: warning lib not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507600/get-rid-of-gcc-usr-bin-ld-warning-lib-not-found) and change my `./configure` command to:

```
./configure CXXFLAGS="-I$HOME/include" LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,$HOME/lib" --with-boost-libdir=$HOME/lib --prefix=$HOME
```

for more details see [Boost 1.51 : "error: could not link against boost_thread !"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408564/boost-1-51-error-could-not-link-against-boost-thread/21957198#21957198)

Answer (score 1):

...and in case you wanted to link your main statically, in your Jamfile add the following to requirements:

```
<link>static
<library>/boost/system//boost_system
```

and perhaps also:

```
<linkflags>-static-libgcc
<linkflags>-static-libstdc++
```