# how to install mongodb drivers for c++ in ubuntu?

Tags: c++, mongodb

I want to develop a fairly simple application using c++ for mongoDB and I follow their tutorials :
http://www.mongodb.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=133415

and for installing driver I followed this one :
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/mongodb-user/-mPG7MDJgm8/nZSiN42DJWIJ
(Waitman Gobble/5 jun answer)

but yet when I try to compile a simple application I will get following error :

> fatal error: client/dbclient.h: No such file or directory

I'm pretty sure the problem is MongoDB c++ driver hasn't installed yet.

How can I install it properly?

Comment: Is the path included in your project's paths?

Comment: not sure what path are you talking about :-?

Comment: But I manage to install the compiled driver using : [sudo scons install] now it installed on "/usr/local/include/mongo/" yet when I try to compile the tutorial I'll get the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you download the driver source code from [here](http://dl.mongodb.org/dl/cxx-driver),

Unpack and unzip

```
tar xzf mongodb-linux-x86_64-v2.0-latest.tgz
```

Then cd into the directory.

```
cd mongo-cxx-driver-v2.0/
```

Then use scons to build

```
scons
```

and install

```
sudo scons install
```

Then to compile code shown in the [tutorial](http://www.mongodb.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=133415#C%2B%2BTutorial-Connecting) you need to also specify the /usr/local/include/mongo directory as a include file search path.

```
sudo  g++ tutorial.cpp -I/usr/local/include/mongo -lmongoclient 
-lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -o tutorial
```

Then to run it you will need to edit the /etc/ld.so.conf file

```
sudo vi /etc/ld.so.conf
```

and add

```
/usr/local/lib
```

Then run

```
sudo ldconfig
```

and run the tutorial

```
$ ./tutorial 
connected ok
```

As an alternative to editing the ld.so.config file you can use the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable. So you would do

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
$ ./tutorial 
connected ok
```

Comment: finally got the error I had to link "boost_system" to g++ as well from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723793/undefined-reference-to-boostsystemsystem-category-when-compiling. if you are one the mongoDB contributor or know them, just tell them their documents are outdated BIG time! better to change their approach or else they will replaced soon enough.

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu packages for development are separate from packages for general use.

In order to make use of the mongodb header files and clientlibraries, you need to `sudo apt-get install mongodb-dev libmongo-client-dev` - this adds the headers that will allow you to `#include` the relevant header files.

This assumes that you've already installed the `libmongo-client` and `mongodb` packages, which contains the client library, although they should be installed when you install the `-dev` packages.