# Get rid of "gcc - /usr/bin/ld: warning lib not found"

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation

I have the following warning during link:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libxxx.so.6, needed by /a/b/c/libyyy.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

Setting environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path_to_libxxx.so.6 silence the warning (adding -Lpath_to_libxxx.so.6 doesn't help).

I have a separate compilation server, where the resulting binary is only compile.
The binary is executed on other server and there the libxxx.so.6 is seen by the binary (checked with `ldd executable`).

Is there're other way to get rid of the warning at compilation time (I have it several times and it's very annoying)?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to add the dynamic library equivalent of `-L`:

```
-Wl,-rpath-link,/path/to/lib
```

This will cause the linker to look for shared libraries in non-standard places, but only for the purpose of verifying the link is correct.

If you want the program to find the library at that location *at run-time*, then there's a similar option to do that:

```
-Wl,-rpath,/path/to/lib
```

But, if your program runs fine without this then you don't need it.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the paths to the needed libraries are known to the runtime linker. This is done by adding a file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ with the needed path. For example, /etc/ld.so.conf.d/foo with the following contents:

```
/usr/local/lib/foo/
```

If you have a very old Linux version, /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ might not be supported, in which case you might have to add the paths directly into the /etc/ld.so.conf file.

After you've done that, you need to update the linker's database by executing the "ldconfig" command.

Comment: I have no root permission in the server the compilation is done. The server is *only* for compilation and the binary won't be executed on it. 1st question is why at *link* time I need take care of runtime environment and 2nd one is how get rid of the warning.

Comment: @dimba You don't have to take care of it. It's just a warning informing you that the binary won't run on the current machine. As for how to disable the warning without using an rpath during linking, I don't know. (Using an rpath is usually not a good idea, unless you bundle libraries with your executable.) If you don't have root permission, then LD_LIBRARY_PATH is your only option.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but [here's a better fix](https://sysprogs.com/w/fixing-rpath-link-issues-with-cross-compilers/):

> ## The root cause:
>
> The problem actually happens when LD invoked by GCC starts resolving
> library dependencies. Both GCC and LD are aware of the sysroot
> containing libraries, however LD may be missing one critical
> component: the /etc/ld.so.conf file. Here’s an exampleld.so.conf file
> from a Raspberry PI system:
>
> include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
>
> The /etc/ld.so.conf.d directory contains the following files:
>
> **00-vmcs.conf:**
> */opt/vc/lib*
>
> **arm-linux-gnueabihf.conf:**
>
> */lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf*
>
> **libc.conf:**
>
> */usr/local/lib*
>
> ## The universal solution
>
> The problem can be easily solved by copying the LD configuration files
> to a location where the cross-toolchain’s LD can find them. There’s
> one pitfall however: if your cross-toolchain was built with MinGW
> (most are), it probably did not have access to the glob() function so
> it won’t be able to parse a wildcard-enabled include statement
> like *.conf. The workaround here is to just manually combine the
> contents of all .conf files from /etc/ld.so.conf.d and paste them
> into **/etc/ld.so.conf**
>
> */opt/vc/lib
>
> /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
>
> /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
>
> /usr/local/lib*
>
> Once you create the ld.so.conf file in the correct folder, your
> toolchain will be able to resolve all shared library references
> automatically and you won’t see that error message again!

Comment: Many thanks, that solved the issue neatly! It is worth mentioning that /etc/ld.so.conf should be created in the toolchain's _target_ sysroot, not the _host_ one.

Comment: Hi! Can you be more specific about what's the "toolchain's target sysroot"? In my application the toolchain is NOT inside the sysroot, they are in separate paths:

* /path-to/sysroot
* /path-to/toolchain

There's already a proper etc.ld.so.conf under /path-to/sysroot/etc, but I still get link issues. Where exactly inside /path-to/toolchain do I need to put the etc.ld.so.conf file?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to silence these warning using command line options would be the -L flag which curiously does not work for you (maybe you can post more details on this). Since the warning is generated by `ld` we could try to use `-Wl,option` to disable a linker warning but from the [documentation of GNU ld](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23.1/ld/Options.htm) however there is no option for (de)activating this warnings.

So this leaves us with writing a wrapper script filtering out this warning or compile a custom version of `ld`.