# colcon could not find thirdparty libraries (Poco)

Tags: cmake, ros2

I am trying to cross-compile ROS2 for Arm. The steps I am following can be found in here: https://github.com/ros2-for-arm/ros2/wiki/ROS2-on-arm-architecture

The build command used is 
`colcon build --symlink-install --cmake-force-configure --cmake-args -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=aarch64_toolchainfile.cmake -DTHIRDPARTY=ON -DBUILD_TESTING:BOOL=OFF`

The poco library cannot be found, however it is in "`/work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/poco_vendor/lib/libPocoFoundation.so.50`" and it is correctly cross-compiled:

```
/work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/poco_vendor/lib/libPocoFoundation.so.50: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=6ba44c72e2162ca056b0dbde681dd4a8b5da5e35, not stripped
```

I wonder where I can modify the CMake script to specify the path to the thirdparty libraries. I tried to specify manually the path to Poco but it did not work:

```
add_library(Poco_import SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(Poco_import PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "/work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/poco_vendor/lib/libPocoFoundation.so.50"
)
```

I also tried adding the path to the Poco library in `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`
(-L) but no success.

Everything look to be compiled correctly, but I got an error at the linking stage:

```
Failed   <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher  [ Exited with code 2 ]
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_minimal_timer
/work/Documents/aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libPocoFoundation.so.50, needed by /work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/rosidl_typesupport_cpp/lib/librosidl_typesupport_cpp.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/work/Documents/aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libyaml.so, needed by /work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/rcl_yaml_param_parser/lib/librcl_yaml_param_parser.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/rcl_yaml_param_parser/lib/librcl_yaml_param_parser.so: undefined reference to `yaml_event_delete'
/work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/rcl_yaml_param_parser/lib/librcl_yaml_param_parser.so: undefined reference to `yaml_parser_parse'
/work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/rosidl_typesupport_cpp/lib/librosidl_typesupport_cpp.so: undefined reference to `Poco::SharedLibrary::getSymbol(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/rcl_yaml_param_parser/lib/librcl_yaml_param_parser.so: undefined reference to `yaml_parser_delete'
/work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/rcl_yaml_param_parser/lib/librcl_yaml_param_parser.so: undefined reference to `yaml_parser_initialize'
/work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/rosidl_typesupport_cpp/lib/librosidl_typesupport_cpp.so: undefined reference to `Poco::SharedLibrary::hasSymbol(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/rosidl_typesupport_cpp/lib/librosidl_typesupport_cpp.so: undefined reference to `Poco::SharedLibrary::SharedLibrary(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/rcl_yaml_param_parser/lib/librcl_yaml_param_parser.so: undefined reference to `yaml_parser_set_input_file'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [timer_lambda] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/timer_lambda.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/work/Documents/aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libPocoFoundation.so.50, needed by /work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/rosidl_typesupport_cpp/lib/librosidl_typesupport_cpp.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/work/Documents/aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/6.1.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libyaml.so, needed by /work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/rcl_yaml_param_parser/lib/librcl_yaml_param_parser.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/rcl_yaml_param_parser/lib/librcl_yaml_param_parser.so: undefined reference to `yaml_event_delete'
/work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/rcl_yaml_param_parser/lib/librcl_yaml_param_parser.so: undefined reference to `yaml_parser_parse'
/work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/rosidl_typesupport_cpp/lib/librosidl_typesupport_cpp.so: undefined reference to `Poco::SharedLibrary::getSymbol(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/rcl_yaml_param_parser/lib/librcl_yaml_param_parser.so: undefined reference to `yaml_parser_delete'
/work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/rcl_yaml_param_parser/lib/librcl_yaml_param_parser.so: undefined reference to `yaml_parser_initialize'
/work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/rosidl_typesupport_cpp/lib/librosidl_typesupport_cpp.so: undefined reference to `Poco::SharedLibrary::hasSymbol(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/rosidl_typesupport_cpp/lib/librosidl_typesupport_cpp.so: undefined reference to `Poco::SharedLibrary::SharedLibrary(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/work/ROS2_Bouncy/ros2_ws/install/rcl_yaml_param_parser/lib/librcl_yaml_param_parser.so: undefined reference to `yaml_parser_set_input_file'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [timer_member_function] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/timer_member_function.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: `-L` flag isn't you case, you need to follow linker suggestions - use `-rpath` option. Look into question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507600/get-rid-of-gcc-usr-bin-ld-warning-lib-not-found for more possible solutions.

Comment: I tried adding set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "path to poco") and 
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE) in the toolchain file but the linker is giving me the same error.

Comment: Hm, most likely you need to assign [CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH.html) variable. Actually, the problem is quite a strange - you have `librosidl_typesupport_cpp.so` library, but cannot use it with additional options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tsyvarev who pointed to me the correct flag.
I added the following to the toolchain file and it solved the issue.

```
set(PATH_POCO_LIB "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/build/poco_vendor/poco_external_project_install/lib/")
set(PATH_YAML_LIB "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/build/libyaml_vendor/libyaml_install/lib/")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH "${PATH_POCO_LIB};${PATH_YAML_LIB}")
```