# C++ Boost: undefined reference to `boost::system::detail::system_category_ncx()`

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I am trying to use Microsoft REST SDK to create a server listening to HTTP requests. My current computer is Ubuntu 18.04, the server code is pretty simple.

I have already installed the library by following the instructions on [libboost official website](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_68_0.html) and I have checked files in `/usr/local/lib/`, there are `libboost_random.so.1.68.0` so I presume that I have libboost library.

However when I try to compile the code with the following command:

`g++ server.cpp -o server -lpthread -lcpprest -lcrypto -lssl -lboost_system`

It shows:

```
/tmp/ccKWADuo.o: In function `boost::system::system_category()':
server.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv[_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv]+0x7): undefined reference to `boost::system::detail::system_category_instance'
/tmp/ccKWADuo.o: In function `boost::system::generic_category()':
server.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6system16generic_categoryEv[_ZN5boost6system16generic_categoryEv]+0x7): undefined reference to `boost::system::detail::generic_category_instance'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: Have you checked there aren't any warnings further up in the compiler output?

Comment: @AlanBirtles no, nothing, I have pasted eveything on this post, I wonder if it's because of the version of boost library.

Comment: Maybe relevant... [undefined reference to boost::system::system_category() when compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9723793/608639)

Answer (score 0):

Boost consists of several independent libraries. Your linker error suggests you are missing `libboost_system.so`. You just mentioned `libboost_random.so` to be in your `/usr/local/lib` but is there also the required `libboost_system.so`?

Comment: yes, it is in `/usr/local/lib/`, sorry for the confusing statement. In fact, under that path there are `libboost_system.so` and `libboost_system.so.1.68.o`

Answer (score 0):

[Problem solved] Reinstalling library `libboost 1.68.0` helps. Error occurs when building from source, fixing those building errors will solve the problem.